# Removing outliers for linear regression (Python)

Tags: python, regression, outliers

I want to remove those 9 orange outlier dots from the graph below, for this I need to calculate the accuracy score for each orange point and pick the 9 lowest. How can I do that? I know functions that can calculate accuracy for whole prediction, but is there any way to do it for each dot?

I tried doing this but x and y values which I get from here do not match the outliers that are on the graph. (I am using sklearn linear regression)

```
score_array = []
for i in range(len(x_train)):
    #reshaping to fit the predict() function
    x = np.array(x_train[i]).reshape(1, -1)
    pred = clf.predict(x)
    # calculating square difference of y_expected and y_predicted
    score = y_train[i]**2 - pred**2
    score_array.append(score) # array containing score for each dot
# larger the difference between squares, higher chance of being an outlier
# sorting array in descending order
score_array = sorted(score_array, key = float, reverse = True)
# first 9 members will have largest difference of squares
# outlier_score array contains score of 9 dots we want to remove
outlier_score = score_array[0:9]
outlier_array_x = []; outlier_array_y = []
# we traverse again to see which x and y result in highest scores
for i in range(len(x_train)):
    x = np.array(x_train[i]).reshape(1, -1)
    pred = clf.predict(x)
    score = y_train[i]**2 - pred**2
    # if the score for current index i is in outlier_score, we get x and y values
    if score in outlier_score:
        outlier_array_x.append(x_train[i])
        outlier_array_y.append(y_train[i])
```

[image: Output with outliers]

EDIT: Thanks to people below I resolved this issue, but now I have trouble actually removing those dots. The length of old arrays were 90 each, new lengths are 81 as expected, but when plotting the graph those 9 outliers remain unaltered.

What would be the best way to remove specific values from the array?
I tried doing this but then x and y values get shuffled resulting in a completely different graph

EDIT 2:

I used this loop to delete the elements:

```
j = 0
for i in index_array:
    i = i - j
    del x_train[i]
    del y_train[i]
    j += 1
```

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: @doctorlove for example array holding x values that are supposed to be outliers are all above 50, which is clearly not the case on graph

Comment: And given the upodate - which probably means we need a new question - do you then *retrain* the data? Where does the new regression line come out? What do you expect to happen to these outliers? They won't be "changed"  - you are just not using them in the training set.

Comment: @doctorlove, yes, I make a different classifier and train it with new data

Comment: And? Then it predicts the same value for the outliers? Oh hang on - what does "the x and y alues get shuiffled" mean?

Comment: @doctorlove for instance, x coordinate 64 appears multiple time in original x_train, when removing 64, it removes first occurrence of that element in list and y value which was supposed to correspond to that 64 now corresponds to completely different x

Comment: Yes - that's the danger of looking for a value - my edit shows you how to use in *index* whcih should avoid this, though the other answer derserves the tick cos it solves the original problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y_train[i]**2 - pred**2` is not the distance between actual and expected.
(Is y_train always larger than pred? Why might this distance metric be *lowest* for the outliers you pointed out?)

Try`(y_train[i] - pred)**2` to get the actual distance.

Comment: that seemed to have worked, I was using abs() before posting here but output was still strange. Now I have problem with removing, length of updated x_train and y_train is lower by nine, but those 9 dots seem to be unaffected

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy tells you how many data points are correctly classified.
This doesn't make sense for single data points, or regression.
You can take other functions, like mean squared error, or any other "distance" from prediction to the actual value.

Your `score` value is doing something like this.
You therefore need to find the points with the largest `score`.
You have a `score_array` which you sort, which you can use directly.
You don't then need to recslculate the predictions and look for floating point values in an array.

Note, using `L = [0.9, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4]` you can use `enumerate(L)` to pair up in index and score/value in `L`:

```
>>> sorted(enumerate(L), key = lambda (i,v) : v, reverse = True)
[(0, 0.9), (3, 0.4), (2, 0.3), (1, 0.1)]
```

Then you can skip over the first n of these. e.g.

```
>>> sorted(enumerate(L), key = lambda (i,v) : v, reverse = True)[2:]
[(2, 0.3), (1, 0.1)]
```

So, instead of

```
score_array = sorted(score_array, key = float, reverse = True)
```

try

```
score_array = sorted(enumerate(score_array), key = lambda (i,v) : v, reverse = True)
```

You can then drop the first few of these, since this contains the index into the x and y values.
You can even ditch anything further away than a certain distance.

---

Edit:

We've observed you need to use the square of the error, not the error of the square, as the other answer shows.

To then get the new training set, use the index from `score_array`, now tuples of (index, value), like this

```
 x_train = [x_train[x[0]] for x in score_array]
```

and similarly for the corresponding y values.

Comment: thank you for help! I came up with a solution of my own, I will write it in post